# Why is there a deadlock here if I comment out printf?

Tags: go, concurrency, deadlock, channel

In the provided code, a deadlock occurs at runtime when I comment out the line fmt.Printf("1a %d\n", value). This behavior is puzzling. However, if I run the program without any changes, it proceeds as expected, and I receive the output noted below. Can anyone suggest why this unusual behavior might occur?

```
2a
2b 0
1a 42
Execution completed.
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan int)
    ch2 := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        value := <-ch1 // Goroutine 1 is waiting to receive from ch1
        fmt.Printf("1a %d\n", value) ### If I comment out this line. I will get a deadlock at runtime.
        ch2 <- value // Goroutine 1 tries to send to ch2
        fmt.Printf("1b %d\n", value)
    }()

    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("2a\n")
        value := <-ch2 // Goroutine 2 is waiting to receive from ch2
        fmt.Printf("2b %d\n", value)
        ch1 <- value // Goroutine 2 tries to send to ch1
        fmt.Printf("2c %d\n", value)
    }()

    // The main goroutine tries to send a value to ch1
    ch1 <- 42
    ch2 <- 0

    // This code will never be reached because of the deadlock
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Execution completed.")
}
```

Comment: `ch2 <- 0` blocks indefinitely because `ch2 <- value` is sent _before_ `ch2 <- 0` and there's no more receive ops for that channel. How the runtime schedules the execution of goroutines is not part of the language spec and is instead a __non-deterministic__ implementation detail.

Comment: FTR: the deadlock may occur with or without the Printf call. It simply depends on who gets to send to ch2 first. If it's main, the program terminates (but only because main doesn't wait for any other goroutines to finish; if it did, you'd have a deadlock in all cases).

Answer (score 0):

First of all your goroutines are not synchronised. This means you cannot guarantee an order in which they will be executed, only scheduler knows. And by your code it's easy situation in which will be double write to non buffered channel with only one read